# Keyboard can not control game display

Tags: python, pygame, cursor, pycharm

I am trying to build a game by pygame in Pychorm. After I create a game display and try to control it by pygame.event.get(),

the cursor still stays at Pychorm and can't fall into my game screen.
While I type down, the cursor moves down in Pychorm but not my game object moves down.

```
#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
#creat game object
ship = Ship(screen)

while True:        
    gf.check_events(ship)


def check_events(ship):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                
            ship.rect.centerx +=  1
```

How to lock cursor on game screen?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve. Are you trying to move the mouse cursor? Or do you want to constrain the mouse cursor, so that it can only be inside of the game window?

Answer (score 0):

I think it takes a tick for Mouse.position to update after the setMousePosition call.

Try:

if Mouse.position[0] > width - 1 or Mouse.position[0] < 1 or Mouse.position[1] > height - 1 or Mouse.position[1] < 1:
render.setMousePosition(own["lastpos"][0], own["lastpos"][1])
else:
own["lastpos"] = Mouse.position

Comment: if not sorry haha i try my best peace and love

Comment: i keeep reading your question and i think i was out of topic lol ,